# How could I access an object value

Tags: php, solr

I have a PHP variable called `$highlightings` which carries highlighting solr response object. The `var_dump` of that variable prints out the following:

```
object(stdClass)#35 (10) {
  ["9955-97-43-7"]=>
  object(stdClass)#36 (1) {
    ["Content"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(216) " أن يتزوج من الجارية إلا في حالة عدم التمكن من التزوج من الحرة انظر : جامع البيان : 5/7 ، زاد المسير في <span class="highlight">علم</span>"
    }
  }
  ["9955-81-27-7"]=>
  object(stdClass)#37 (1) {
    ["Content"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(176) " <span class="highlight">العلمية</span> ، بيروت ) . المغني لابن قدامة : 4/25 .
(2) - صحيح مسلم : 3/1211 ، البحر الرائق : 6/210 ."
    }
  }.....
```

I want to access the first string of that object (*216 length*) but I could not. I tried:

```
$highlightings["9955-97-43-7"]->Content[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parent is an object with a hypenated propety, try to use `{}`:

```
echo $highlightings->{'9955-97-43-7'}->Content[0];
```